# How to add attributes to custom elements?

Tags: javascript, html, web-component

I am trying to add attributes in my custom elements and use it within my new element, but having a hard time with the syntax. I have seen [this article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/), but not really clear on it's usage. How can I declare and use the custom "label" attribute in my created callback to render it?

```
<current-date foo="Today is: "></current-date>

<script>
  document.registerElement('current-date', {
    prototype: {
      createdCallback: function() {
        this.innerHTML = this.foo + new Date();
      },
      foo: {
        value: function() {
          alert('foo() called');
        }
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

http://jsbin.com/UdOwizU/4/ (only works in Google Canary)

Comment: It might be that the prototype needs to be a Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype) object and not a literal object.

Comment: To truly utilize attributes in the way you want, you really need to being using `attributeChanged`. As I noted in my mysteriously down-voted answer below, it is the only way you'll be able to respond to changes in the attribute. I actually worked on the W3 Web Component specs, so I assure you the advice I'm giving you is sound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
<body>
  <current-date label="Today is: "></current-date>

  <script>
    document.registerElement('current-date', {
      prototype: {
        createdCallback: function() {
          this.foo = {value: function() {
            return this.attributes.getNamedItem("label").value;
          }},
          this.innerHTML = this.foo.value.call(this) + new Date();
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

http://jsbin.com/ivaWUyAL/3/edit

Answer (score 1):

What you're probably looking for is the `attributeChangedCallback`, it will give you a chance to run user code whenever an attribute is set, removed, or modified --> http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/custom/#types-of-callbacks

Comment: How did I get voted down on this? This is THE way to listen for attribute changes and use attributes to feed into your component code...I worked on these specs.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I get you wrong, but have you tried using `setAttribute()`?

I also can't try `registerElement`, but it works the "usual" way:

```
var el = document.createElement( 'current-date' );
el.setAttribute( 'label', new Date() );
document.body.appendChild( el );
```

In your case this should be something like:

```
createdCallback: function() {
    this.innerHTML = this.foo + new Date();
    this.setAttribute( 'label', this.getAttribute( 'label' ) + new Date() );
}
```